Typeerror cannot read properties of undefined (reading setcontent url ))
I am using a DevExpress Splitter pane to display a treeview on the left and when clicked need to load a url on the right pane.
Below is the code
@Html.DevExpress().Splitter(settings => {
settings.Name = "HelpSplitter";
settings.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);
settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
settings.ResizingMode = ResizingMode.Live;
settings.ShowCollapseBackwardButton = true;
settings.ShowCollapseForwardButton = true;
settings.Theme = CMS.Web.Constants.DefaultConstants.SYSTEM_THEME;
settings.ClientVisible = true;
settings.Style["border"] = "0";
settings.AllowResize = true;

settings.Panes.Add(pane =>
{
    pane.Name = "Left Pane";
    pane.MinSize = 350;
    pane.AllowResize = DefaultBoolean.True;
    pane.ShowSeparatorImage = DefaultBoolean.True;
    pane.SetContent(() =>
    {
        ViewContext.Writer.Write("Left Pane");
    });

    pane.Panes.Add(treeviewPane =>
    {
        treeviewPane.Name = "TreeViewPane";
        treeviewPane.ContentUrlIFrameTitle = "TreeViewPane";
        treeviewPane.AutoWidth = true;
        treeviewPane.MinSize = 400;
        treeviewPane.AutoHeight = false;
        treeviewPane.Size = Unit.Percentage(85);
        treeviewPane.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
        treeviewPane.ShowSeparatorImage = DefaultBoolean.True;
        treeviewPane.AllowResize = DefaultBoolean.True;
        treeviewPane.SetContent(() =>
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("_HelpDetails", Model);
        });
    });
});

settings.Panes.Add(pane =>
{
    pane.Name = "DetailHelpPane";
    pane.ContentUrlIFrameTitle = "DetailHelpPane";
    pane.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
    pane.MinSize = 1;
    pane.AllowResize = DefaultBoolean.True;
    pane.ContentUrl = "about:blank";
}); }).GetHtml()

The below javascript loads the Right pane
function loadDetailPane(item) {
    var fileName = null;
    if (item.FileName != '') {
        if (isValidUrl(item.FileName)) {
            fileName = `${item.FileName}`;
        }
        else {
            fileName = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}/${item.FileName}`;
        }
    }

if (fileName != null) {
    while (true) {
        var isComponentAvailable = checkDetailHelpPaneAvailability();
        if (isComponentAvailable === true) {
            var detailPane = HelpSplitter.GetPaneByName('DetailHelpPane');
            if (detailPane !== null && typeof detailPane !== 'undefined') {
                detailPane.SetContentUrl(fileName);
            }
            break;
        }
    }        
} }

function checkDetailHelpPaneAvailability() {
let pane = HelpSplitter.GetPaneByName('DetailHelpPane');
let DetailHelpPaneIframe = pane.GetContentIFrame();
if (pane !== null && typeof pane !== 'undefined')
    return true;
else
    return false;     }

How can I ensure the content will load for sure, as I am encountering an error on pane.SetContentUrl(fileName); in some instances. As Pane is null or undefined.
